# UI router navigating to parent state changes query string params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

After navigating to a parent state with a query string and `reloadOnSearch=false`, if the query string is then updated with a search, child states can then inherit this query string.

If the child state then navigates back up to the parent state, the query string will reset to the first query string, and not the update.  How can I retain the updated query string?

Here's a plunkr that demonstrates the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/krh7djem9oaXK7OzMJKz?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aa3GogrDFv6TqdESwyM6?p=preview)

When updating the params instead of using `$location.search('type', newVal)` I set it to :

```
$scope.$watch('type', function(newVal) {
$stateParams.type=newVal;
//$state.go('list', { type: newVal });
```

}, true);

and it works.